# Regex replace matched subexpression (and nothing else)?

Tags: php, regex

I've used regex for ages but somehow I managed to never run into something like this.

I'm looking to do some bulk search/replace operations within a file where I need to replace some data within tag-like elements.  For example, converting `<DelayEvent>13A</DelayEvent>` to just `<DelayEvent>X</DelayEvent>` where `X` might be different for each.

The current way I'm doing this is such:

```
$new_data = preg_replace('|<DelayEvent>(\w+)</DelayEvent>|', '<DelayEvent>X</DelayEvent>', $data);
```

I can shorten this a bit to:

```
$new_data = preg_replace('|(<DelayEvent>)(\w+)(</DelayEvent>)|', '${1}X${2}', $data);
```

But really all I want to do is simulate a "replace text between tags T with X".

Is there a way to do such a thing?  In essence I'm trying to prevent having to match all the surrounding data and reassembling it later.  I just want to replace a given matched sub-expression with something else.

*Edit:* The data is not XML, although it does what appear to be tag-like elements.  I know better than parsing HTML and XML with RegEx. ;)

Comment: More information required - is the document some kind of markup? any tag or just specific ones? Any content in tags or specific pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$new_data = preg_replace('|(?<=<DelayEvent>)\w+(?=</DelayEvent>)|', 'X', $data);
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/DlaDV)